# How measure the detail stack memory limit

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have to measure stack memory size(max limit) in c#.

So, I want to ask a question about measuring stack memory limit size.

===

This is assignment. So measuring present stack memory is important.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To 'TheGeneral' : just assignment(presentation)

Comment: OP - use @TheGeneral to get someone's attention. The site will actually notify them! :)

Comment: Please share with us the **exact** assignment details. The whole thing. So we know the full context.

Comment: To mjwills : I edit my practice code. ('enter image description here')

Comment: @Zenexer That doesn't tell you how to get the current max in code.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I believe the answer is the same: .NET doesn’t provide a true way to determine the max stack size. You can use some shenanigans on Windows, but it’s not part of .NET.

Comment: @김현준, just to clarify, .NET doesn't provide a way to determine the stack size dynamically. It also doesn't allow you to catch a StackOverflowException.  The default stack sizes are provided in the question of which this has been marked as a duplicate.